# Can you help me figure out this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, list

I'm working on a homework assignment and as a "hint" we are told to find the following algorithm, and then prove it to the necessary answer.

Let L(1), L(2), .., L(k) be sorted lists of n elements each. Give a O(kn logk) space algorithm that supports the O(log n + t) Locate operation, which returns the location of t items.

Ideally, I will be able to use this algorithm to give me some insight into achieving a better solution (which is what the assignment wants), but this less effecient algorithm is supposed to inspire me, but I can't figure it out. Any thoughts or know what this algorithm is? Thanks!

Comment: The homework is given to you so you learn from it. If you ask here, you don't learn from it, you only learn how to ask a question. Trust me, it's better to try to find out yourself and give the wrong answer perhaps than to ask here and give the right answer (given to you by others) as you then don't learn anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you googled for O(kn logk) ?  That seems to be a pretty unique big-O signature.

Here's my first result: 
**MergeSort** --> [What is the relation between merges and number of items in a in k-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658502/what-is-the-relation-between-merges-and-number-of-items-in-a-in-k-way-merge/659214#659214)

Comment: One immediate problems I see: MergeSort is an O(k n log n) *time* algorithm. Question was for *space* complexity, not time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find one that gives O(log n + t) time, but I had a thought that might or might not help...

O(kn log k) is the size of a table mapping each possible item to the number of the list containing it. However, using that to find which list to look in still results in a t*O(log n)-lookup time for t elements, so it's not really what's asked for...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a sorting function since you already have 2 sorted lists. Sounds like Binary Search to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it asks you to find an inefficient algorithm first, then use that to make an efficient one. It sounds like a linear search of lists, each with a binary search to look through them. It will require O(2t) space, because you need to copy down the "coordinates" of the t items.

Answer (score 0):

Even with that ugly big O notation I think it's a Binary Search problem because you have the sorted lists.

Space complexity remains the same because it's a divide and conquer algorithm,so you won't have problems there.

To be very sure is the t outside the logn, something like O((logn)+t)?

Comment: And n represents the number of items or elements?

Answer (score -1):

ehh... sounds like... binary search? [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search)